# Installing langchain and kor in PyCharm failling due to failed building wheel for greenlet

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I want to use `kor` and `langchain` in `PyCharm`. I import the packages using:

```
# kor
from kor.extraction import create_extraction_chain
from kor.nodes import Object, Text, Number

# LangChain Models
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
```

But installing the latest versions of both packages in `PyCharm` I run into the same error:

> ```
>   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
> ```
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
> error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
> [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet ERROR:
> Could not build wheels for greenlet, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects

Building `greenlet` on its own for my os, results in the same error. However, installing the packages in the terminal with pip works fine. The problem only occurs in `PyCharm`.

I use

- macOS 13.3.1
- Python 3.9.9
- PyCharm 2023.1.1 (Community Edition)
- Pip 23.1.2

**Edit:**

I tried the following in the terminal to install `langchain` to `PyCharm`

```
> /Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_openai/venv/bin/activate
> /Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_openai/venv/bin/python
> /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py
> install langchain
```

It gives me, even though the file `packaging_tool.py` is in the directory:

> can't open file
> /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py:
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory